# Any Interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be covered with countably many cubes

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $I=[a_1,b_1]\times\dots\times[a_n ,b_n]\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\epsilon\gt0$.

Prove that there exist closed ***cubes*** (equal side length in all dimensions) $\{Q_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ s.t. :

$1.\space \space I\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i$

$2.\space \space \forall i\ne j: Q_i^{int}\cap Q_j^{int}=\emptyset$

$3.\space \space v(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i)\le v(I)+\epsilon$

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $Q$ in part 3? Also does cube here imply equal side length in all dimensions?

Comment: @kccu Thank you for your comment. I have adjusted the question now.

Comment: You can do that with finitely many cubes.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Can you explain how?

Comment: Some good direction here would be to start by thinking about golden rectangles: if you start with a golden rectangle and cut a square off one end, you get a smaller golden rectangle. If you repeatedly cut off squares like this , you can do it in a way that puts the remaining rectangle in the corner of the original rectangle, and you can do this process far enough to make the remaining  rectangle arbitrarily small , so that an arbitrarily small square can contain it. Should be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider the case where $d_i:=b_i-a_i$ is rational for all $i$. In this case we can write each $d_i$ with a common denominator $N$. Now show that you can decompose $I$ into finitely many cubes each of side length $\frac{1}{N}$.

Next consider the case where not all the $d_i$ are rational. For any fixed $\delta>0$, we can find rationals $r_i$ such that $r_i \leq d_i+\delta$ for all $i$. Now extend the side lengths of $I$ to be $r_i$ in dimension $i$ (e.g., set $I' = [a_1,a_1+r_1]\times \cdots \times [a_n,a_n+r_n] \supseteq I$). As in case 1, we can cover $I'$ with finitely many cubes, and the sum of their volumes will be $v(I')$. It remains to show you can choose $\delta$ so that $v(I') \leq v(I)+\epsilon$.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to show the first part?

Comment: Since the length of each side of $I$ is a whole number multiple of $\frac{1}{N}$ you are essentially dividing $I$ into an even grid of cubes.

Comment: I understand that intuitively but I can't quite figure how to write the union formally

Comment: You will have to enumerate the sides that define the cubes. For instance, in the 1-dimensional case if $b-a=\frac{R}{N}$, the cubes will be $\left\{\left[a+\frac{k}{N}, a+\frac{k+1}{N}\right] : k \in \{0,1,...,R-1\}\right\}$. In the two-dimensional case, say $b_1-a_1=\frac{R_1}{N}$ and $b_2-a_2=\frac{R_2}{N}$. Then for each $0 \leq k_1 <R_1$ and each $0 \leq k_2<R_2$ you will have a cube $\left[a_1+\frac{k_1}{N},a_1+\frac{k_1+1}{N}\right] \times \left[a_2+\frac{k_2}{N},a_2+\frac{k_2+1}{N}\right]$. Drawing a picture for the 2d case might help you see how to generalize.